# What does the little character 'a' (`ª`) mean when pasting text?

Tags: cut-copy-paste, powershell

I'm very new to Vim. I use Vim in PowerShell on Windows 11. On normal mode I press <kbd>p</kbd> to paste a text, but instead only this character `ª` shows up. What does this mean?

Typing `"*p`: or `:reg "` both result:

```
Type Name Content
  l  ""   Type Name Content^J
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

Comment: It means nothing but, if the unnamed register doesn't contain `ª` (check with `:reg "`), then it might be a sign that something is broken somewhere in the chain terminal emulator -> shell -> Vim. Try again without your config files to see if the problem persists: `$ vim --clean`.

Comment: What if you type `"*p` instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Vim use the `"` register when pasting that do not content the system clipboard by default.

The clipboard content is in the `*` register. If you want to past the content of the system clipboard you have to hit: `"*p`.

You can change that behavior by setting the `clipboard` option by adding the following line in your `~\_vimrc` file:

```
set clipboard=unnamed
```

With this setting:

- The past operation is by default from the `*` register (it use the system clipboard by default)
- The yank operation not only set the `"` by default but also the `*` register (it copy to the system clipboard by default)

Comment: I still has to use `"*p`. Is there a way to only use `p`?

Comment: If you change the setting I proposed (by adding the corresponding line in your `= /_vimrc`) you can use `p` (I have done for myself :-) ).

Comment: hmm, I did do that but I still have to use `"*p`. If I press `p` now the result is `Type Name Content`

Comment: Did you copy/yank something in the meantime?

Comment: I did, but the point is I copy text from outside, which goes to the system clipboard. And `set clipboard=unnamed` doesn't seem to change the keys required to use the system clipboard

Comment: I'm unsure you sucessfully change the `clipboard` setting ;-) What is the result of the command: `:set clipboard?`?

Comment: ohhhh I get it. It's the command for vim, not the terminal 

Comment: Good, I should have been more clear :-)